# nodejs send mp3 from another server to the client

Tags: node.js, express, curl, audio, mp3

I have an express server it grabs stuff from my other server, edits it, and sends it to the client using the `curl` library (I tried `request` but it did the same thing). Everything works great except when I try sneding an MP3 file. If I try that then Chrome can't decode the MP3. However, If I access the MP3 from the original server it decodes fine and plays. I don't edit the MP3's. Here is what my code looks like:

```
// server2.example.com source

const curl = require("curl");
const edit = (b, p) => {};
const express = require("express");

/* ... express app stuff ... */

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    curl.get(
        "http://server1.example.com" + req.path, {},
        (err, response, body) => {
            if (err) return;

            res.type(response.headers["content-type"]).status(response.statusCode).send(edit(body, patches));
        }
    );
});

app.listen(80);
```

Once again the file is un-edited and the exact same file as the one on `server1`. Here is a screenshot of what I see when visiting `server1.example.com/audio.mp3` versus `server2.example.com/audio.mp3`:

[server2.example.com/audio.mp3 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZl8Q.png)

[server1.example.com/audio.mp3 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2DXl.png)

Comment: What happens if you try an mp4 video file? Can you open the dev tools and screenshot the network requests that Chrome makes? I'm guessing the problem is due to range requests.

Comment: Have you tried comparing HTTP headers from both servers?  If you save the MP3 files, served by both servers, to disk, and calculate hashes on the files, do they match?

Comment: Why don't you redirect to that other server instead?